# Could not resolve com.github.Polidea:MultiPlatformBleAdapter:0.1.7

Tags: rxandroidble, react-native-ble-plx

*How to fix this problem after install react-native-ble-plx.Is there any solution for direct react native installation instead of bridging native modules?*

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the [configuration process](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx#configuration--installation) — without the `2. npx react-native link react-native-ble-plx` step as autolinking should work. Other steps are needed though.

Comment: already follow these all configuration process

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

1. In android/build.gradle moved `maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }` respository to bottom after `jcenter()` instead of before `jcenter()`
2. In Android Studio performed gradle sync
3. Then executed `react-native run-android`.